# Commerce Dependencies Management (Nuget maybe)

Tags: sitecore-commerce, nuget, dependency-management

We are currently implementing **Commerce solution** based on **SXA**-commerce approach (using Helix-architecture). We use & extend `Sitecore.Commerce.XA.*.dll` libraries.

So, for example, if we want to extend `Account` module, we have our custom `ProjectName.Feature.Account` project, where Sitecore-dll is referenced in this way:

```xml
<Reference Include="Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Account">   
    <HintPath>
      $(SITECORE_PATH)\bin\Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Account.dll
    </HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Where `SITECORE_PATH` is environment variable, that set to Sitecore IIS server path.

But I think, **it's bad approach**.

Is there another way to manage these references? Which approache you use in your team? Maybe there's **Nuget**, that could be used to this?

P.S. I know, there is [Sitecore Nuget Gallery](https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery), but I'm unable to find XA-libs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about versions and such, but I can find the Account feature Commerce XA in the nuget feed:
https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-commerce-packages/package/nuget/Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Feature.Account

So Nuget would be your answer indeed. By browsing the Commerce packages (https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-commerce-packages) on the myget site and searching for "XA" I found quite some Commerce XA feature and foundation references.

Comment: Thanks! Will review it, as we use `1.2.0`, but in Nuget `1.4.15`.

Comment: If the ones you need are not there, contact Support and ask them to add the versions ;)